# Keyword validation in Google Plus textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with jQuery validation. I want to validate a Google Plus textbox. I want that if the user has not specifically entered `google.com`  with his entered link then the error message should be displayed.

I tried with following code but it's not working. How can I do this?

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter google plus Profile Link" name="google_link" id="google_link">
```

```js
(function($, W, D) {
  var JQUERY4U = {};
  JQUERY4U.UTIL = {
    setupFormValidation: function() {
      //form validation rules
      $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
          google_link: {
            required: true,
            url: true
          },
        },
        messages: {
        google_link: "Please Enter valid link",
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where in your code are you telling it the user must enter google.com ?

Comment: Google Plus will be discontinued starting April 2nd. Why would you still want to do something with it?

Comment: @ChristophHerold: okay,suppose this is facebook field instead of google then i want if someone entered any link then that link must contain "facebook.com"..hope you understand my point

Comment: @JeffUK: i mean to say if someone/user entered (i already mentioned my code)

Comment: I understand what you want to do, I don't see any attempt in your code to do that,  what have you tried so far?

Comment: @JeffUK: i tried with following code

google_link: {
                      required: true,
                       url:true,
                      pattern: [google.com/], 
                  },